# Create staff user in Django

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to create a staff user in Django with

```
UserModel.objects.create_user(username="A", email="a@a.com", password="a", is_staff=True)
```

but in UserManager in Django at https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/models.py it says

```
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    use_in_migrations = True

    def _create_user(self, username, email, password,
                     is_staff, is_superuser, **extra_fields):
        """
        Creates and saves a User with the given username, email and password.
        """
        if not username:
            raise ValueError('The given username must be set')
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(username=username, email=email,
                          is_staff=is_staff, is_superuser=is_superuser,
                          **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_user(self, username, email=None, password=None, **extra_fields):
        return self._create_user(username, email, password, False, False,
                                 **extra_fields)

    def create_superuser(self, username, email, password, **extra_fields):
        return self._create_user(username, email, password, True, True,
                                 **extra_fields)
```

so when trying to set `is_staff = False` it will always override this field with `is_staff = True` unless I use `create_superuser` instead of `create_user`; however, `create_superuser` also sets `is_superuser = True`.

Have they forgot to create the method `create_staff_user` in Django? :-)

Comment: The Django core team is very receptive to pull requests, so please don't be afraid to submit one.

Comment: You always have the options of making a `.update` to this user

Comment: I opened a ticket https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/25009 and this is the commit: https://github.com/django/django/commit/e75b614640c206bf6d0b1c9d32c54434ea719582

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, I don't think that 'they' forgot the create_staff_method.

This is the [pull request](https://github.com/bak1an/django/commit/dc2f67679712412e2f8bdfbecc340f796d6dbc24) that gave birth to the `_create_user` method and the reason for doing so is:

> don't raise db signals twice when creating superuser

Both create_user and create_superuser methods make use of the same private method. Understanding this, and knowing that there are no true private methods in Python makes utilising _create_user directly an option. But an ugly option.

The create_user method is extra method for your convenience. You are right that calling it with `is_staff=True` won't give the expected result. I think that is **the real bug**. The error is:

> TypeError: _create_user() got multiple values for keyword argument
>   'is_staff'

Your code (username is a positional argument):

```
User.objects.create_user('john', email='lennon@thebeatles.com', password='johnpassword', is_staff=True)
```

What the documentation on creating users suggest:

```
user = User.objects.create_user('john', 'lennon@thebeatles.com', 'johnpassword')  
user.is_staff=True 
user.save()
```

But this way we are calling save twice. :/

The UserManager is a subclass of BaseUserManager which is a subclass of Manager. So you can also do:

```
email = normalize_email('lennon@thebeatles.com')
user = User.objects.create(username='john',
    email=email, is_staff=True )
user.set_password(password)
user.save()
```

Since explicit is better than implicit and simple is better than complex... I would go for the most basic and simple `User.objects.create`. Or wait for https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/25009 to land.

Comment: Thank you. But it seems that password is setted incorrectly when I'm creating user with your last suggestion

Comment: Yep, and the email isn't normalized. Updated the answer.

Answer (score -6):

That's intentional. Only anonymous users are `is_staff=False`. All saved users must be staff or super user. More info. [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/auth/#anonymous-users)

Comment: That not True. You are right that **anonymous** users always have is_staff false but authenticated users can be both true and false. The question asked is about creating users.

Comment: What 'that command' do you mean? When users are created, they are no longer anonymous, so the docs you refer to do not apply anymore.

Comment: You are right, create_user won't work if you give is_staff. Feature or bug... Thats the question. Not many projects need to create staff programmatically. And even less wil use the modelMangers create_user. There are so many other ways create users with is_staff and not bump into this feature/bug.

Comment: IMHO it's not a bug, just a feature/convention :)