# How to set user as staff in django by default

Tags: django, django-models

Im using default authentication in django and i want to set user as staff while new user is signing up.
how do i set is_staff =True.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30711544/create-staff-user-in-django

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create staff user in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30711544/create-staff-user-in-django)

Comment: Thnk you. I got it